# O que caracteriza um projeto "CRUD básico"?

Tags: terminologia, crud

Volta e meia aparece uma pergunta falando sobre aplicação "CRUD básico".

Entendo que a aplicação contém basicamente as chamadas "telas de cadastro", de onde manipulam tabelas nas quais se aplicam a quatro operações: Create (inserção), Read (consulta), Update (atualização) e Delete (exclusão).

Porém a definição pode não ser muito clara para alguns. Particularmente nunca tive que implementar essas telas integralmente (por sorte ou por azar), então não tenho a visão sistêmica de como são implementadas.

Existe alguma coisa além disso que seja importante saber?

Algo mais que esteja implícito na dita expressão?

Comment: Pra mim é algo bem informal, CRUD é CRUD. Talvez básico seja algo que realmente é só os dados bem simples, com uma validação mínima, sem ter que as telas fazer malabarismo, provavelmente uma entrada *master-detail* não conte. Mas vai saber.

Comment: Algo que isso se contrapõe a cadastros com subitens? Tipo, há cadastros em que se deve cadastrar a informação central (cabeçalho?) e uma lista de informações filhas. Por exemplo, um produto contém lotes que por sua vez tem validades e números de lote distintos

Comment: Relacionada: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/379067/what-is-a-crud-system

Comment: Seria conveniente uma descrição do que você considera "CRUD básico".

Comment: @BrewertonSantos Descrevi como pude na pergunta, não tenho mais detalhes porque numa fiz um.

Answer (score 3):

Como descrito no [artigo do blog WordPress Descomplicado](https://wordpressdescomplicado.com.br/o-que-e-um-crud/):

> CRUD é o acrônimo da expressão do idioma Inglês, Create (Criação),
>   Read (Consulta), Update (Atualização) e Delete (Destruição). Este
>   acrônimo é comumente utilizado para definir as quatro operações
>   básicas usadas em Banco de Dados Relacionais.

Portanto, o termo CRUD refere-se mais as operações, e não ao sistema em si, no entanto, de acordo com a Wikipédia:

> CRUD são as quatro operações básicas utilizadas em bases de dados
>   relacionais fornecidas aos utilizadores do sistema. Outros acrônimos
>   podem ser usados para definir as mesmas operações: ABCD: Add, Browse,
>   Change and Delete BREAD: Browse, Read, Edit, Add and Delete VADE:
>   View, Add, Delete, Edit.

Pode-se fazer então uma distinção entre os tipos de consulta presentes no sistema, penso então que um sistema CRUD Básico seria aquele que realiza apenas estas quatro operações sem o uso de outros recursos dos bancos de dados relacionais.
Vale a pena ler também o seguinte artigo da **Code Academy** sobre *CRUD e serviços REST*: [What is CRUD?](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/what-is-crud)

Comment: O problema dessa definição é que ela foca no explícito (que já foi citado na pergunta) e não no implícito (os cadastros, validações, etc. que eventualmente precisam ser feitos). É preciso a experiência de alguém com uma aplicação CRUD para citar essa parte implícita. Em relação ao argumento de que CRUD se refere mais ao banco de dados, nesse caso a pergunta pode ser refeita para "Como funcionaria uma aplicação simples de cadastro baseada em CRUD"?

Comment: Penso que então a resposta seria que consiste em uma aplicação com os elementos de crud(criar, ler, atualizar e deletar registros) e as suas regras de negócios e persistências de dados específicas.

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns tipos de páginas que entram no conceito do CRUD.

Claro, existem as páginas principais que justificam o nome CRUD (**C**reate **R**ead **U**pdate **D**elete) representadas em DAO e DTO (**D**ata **A**ccess **O**bject e **D**ata **T**ransfer **O**bject, respectivamente), mas o CRUD por si só representa a forma representar (computacionalmente) e manipular os dados. No geral na arquitetura MVC (**M**odel-**V**iew-**C**ontrol) o CRUD representa a camada entre o Model e o View, sendo manipulada pelo Control.

Para isso ser possível são necessárias as páginas que interagem com o CRUD da forma como o sistema deve reagir, e isso depende do sistema (afinal existem n formas de desenvolvimento, e a que tem tomado mais força ultimamente é o SPA - Single Page Aplication graças a ferramentas como ReactJs ou VueJs), e nesse caso as páginas intermediárias tomam conta.

Por exemplo, imagine o fluxo de dados numa tela que mostra os usuários de um sistema e você precisa fazer uma interação entre os resultados das Querys do banco nessa página intermediária (tipo algum cálculo mais complexo que deve ser feito antes de chegar na View). logo o fluxo seria:
Sistema solicita -> página intermediária seleciona quais páginas do CRUD vão ser usadas -> CRUD lê os dados do banco (n leituras de n tabelas, agrupadas ou não) -> Dados chegam na página intermediária e são processadas -> dados tratados vão pra camada mais alta (seja direto pra View ou para o control para serem reinseridos na view)